# create a trigger to alter table add column based on inserted row

Tags: mysql, triggers, alter-table

I have two tables in a database named as follows:

```
1. state_master
+---------------+-------------------+
|      state_id |        state_name |
+---------------+-------------------+
|             1 |               new |
|             2 |          assigned |
|             3 |       in_progress |
|             4 |           on_hold |
|             5 |            closed |
+---------------+-------------------+



2. store_complaint_state_count
+----------+-----+--------+------------+-------+------+
| store_id | new |assigned| in_progress|on_hold|closed|          
| 101      | 1   |2       | 2          |0      |0     |
| 102      | 5   |4       | 1          |0      |2     |
+----------+-----+--------+------------+-------+------+
```

Now I want to add another row in state_master state_id =6 and state_name=reopen.
I want to create a trigger which can alter table store_complaint_state_count and add column reopen in it.

I've created a procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `alterTablestorewisecomplaintcount`(in state int )
BEGIN
    alter table storewisecomplaintcount
    add column state INT UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;

END
```

And a trigger:

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER
    TRIGGER `nxtlife_sfcms_db_v2`.`complaint_state_AFTER_INSERT`
    AFTER INSERT ON `complaint_state`

FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

call alterTablestorewisecomplaintcount(new.state_value);

END
```

But it throws an error at the time of insertion:

> ERROR 1422: 1422: Explicit or implicit commit is not allowed in stored function or trigger.

Comment: Creating a trigger for that sounds like a great waste of time for something you'll do once in a blue moon. If you must, write a stored procedure to do the insertion and modification.

Comment: if the problem can be solved by another way please suggest me.

Comment: Just do it manually.

Comment: Like @Mat, I would not recommend changing the schema from a trigger.

Comment: You should think about redo your design.

Comment: @dhyanandra : that does not make sense. How should your tables/data  look like after adding the new row to add_master?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trigger shouldn't be used that way; instead of every time altering the able and adding a column; you should use a single column say `Status` which will contain all the different status values like

```
store_complaint_state_count: Status varchar(20);

Status
new 
assigned
in_progress
on_hold
closed
reopen
```

Then you can modify your trigger code to populate that value to `store_complaint_state_count` table

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER
    TRIGGER `nxtlife_sfcms_db_v2`.`complaint_state_AFTER_INSERT`
    AFTER INSERT ON `complaint_state`

FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

INSERT INTO store_complaint_state_count (store_id, `Status`) VALUES(105, new.state_name);

END
```

Comment: but it requires more space

Comment: @dhyanandrasingh, Why you are space constrained? How much more space will it occupy that your query performance will suffer? Moreover, it's a much better design than what currently you opted for. Rest, is upto you.

Answer (score 2):

you are not allowed to do ALTER or DROP operation on triggers. these are the implicit commits that you see in the error message (see more details [here](http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/2012/06/05/implicit-commit-functions/))

Even if it would be possible by some workaround, this is wrong design. If you could do what you wanted- the first insert to the table would add the column, and from then on- all other inserts would have failed since the column already exists

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can create table and log all events in table.

```
create table dbLOG (Id Int Identity(1,1),PostTime 
VARCHAR(50),ServerName VARCHAR(25),UserName VARCHAR(15),CommandText 
   VARCHAR(MAX))
        go

                CREATE TRIGGER [db_LOG]
                ON DATABASE 
                FOR create_table,alter_table,drop_table
                ,create_PROCEDURE, alter_PROCEDURE,drop_PROCEDURE
                ,ALTER_function,create_function,drop_function
                ,ALTER_trigger,create_trigger,drop_trigger
               AS
               SET NOCOUNT ON
               DECLARE @xEvent XML
            SET @xEvent = eventdata() --capture eventdata regarding SQL statement user have fired
            INSERT INTO dbLOG VALUES(
            REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @xEvent.query('data(/EVENT_INSTANCE/PostTime)')),'T', ' '),
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), @xEvent.query('data(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ServerName)')),
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), @xEvent.query('data(/EVENT_INSTANCE/UserName)')),
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), @xEvent.query('data(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand/CommandText)'))
            )
```